# Cannot update maven on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, maven-3

I'm not able to update maven to the latest version, which as of time of writing is 3.8.6:

```
$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.6.3
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 17.0.5, vendor: Private Build, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.15.0-53-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix" 
$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 https://repo.saltproject.io/py3/ubuntu/20.04/amd64/archive/3004.1 focal InRelease
Get:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease [57.7 kB]                                                                    
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/shutter/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                 
Hit:4 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                                                                         
Hit:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                
Hit:6 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                                                          
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/blaze/rtbth-dkms/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                      
Hit:8 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                   
Hit:9 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                                                           
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                       
Hit:13 https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/focal pgadmin4 InRelease                                               
Hit:11 https://scala.jfrog.io/artifactory/debian all InRelease        
Ign:12 https://scala.jfrog.io/artifactory/debian  InRelease
Hit:14 https://scala.jfrog.io/artifactory/debian  Release
Fetched 57.7 kB in 2s (25.6 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
$ sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install maven
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
maven is already the newest version (3.6.3-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
```

It doesn't seem to find newer versions. Any idea?

Comment: Try to do `sudo do-release-upgrade` on the terminal to upgrade the OS. then try to update maven.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the newest version by yourself.

[This](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-maven-on-ubuntu) may help you to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The apt package isn't updated yet. You either have to wait for this to be updated, or try and find the package from maven themself.